# Showing that the expected value of the estimator is equal to the estimate

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I'm really struggling with a question I've been working on, any help would be super appreciated.

If I were given a random sample $X_1,\dots,X_n$ from a distribution for which the joint density has the regular exponential form:

$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n;\theta)=\frac{b(x_1,\dots,x_n)\exp\big(c(\theta) {\textbf{T}}(x_1,\dots,x_n)\big)}{a(\theta)}$$

How would I go about showing that the maximum likelihood estimate (for the case where there is only one parameter and $c(\theta)=\theta$ ) satisfies the equation:

$$E\big[{\bf{T}} (X_1,\dots,X_n) \big] = {\bf{T}}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$$

My thoughts are to use the expectation of the score statistic equalling zero, but I can't seem to piece it together.

Thanks guys

Comment: I do not quite understand your question.  Suppose $X_i$ has an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$ and I observe two values $x_1$ and $x_2$.  That will give a maximum likelihood estimate of $\hat\lambda = \frac{2}{x_1+x_2}$.  What is that supposed to be equal to?

Comment: @Henry sorry I should have been more clear in the question - I have updated.

Comment: I am still not clear.  My example has a joint density of $f(x_1,x_2;\lambda)=\lambda^2\exp(-\lambda(x_1+x_2))$ so of your form.  So if you use $T(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$, what is supposed to be equal to $x_1+x_2$?  Are you saying $\mathbb E\left[X_1+X_2 \mid \lambda = \frac{2}{x_1+x_2}\right] = x_1+x_2$?

Comment: I think I am supposed to be able to show that the ML estimator of $\theta$ satisfies $E[T(X_1,\dots,X_n)] = T(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ for all joint density functions of the form in the question, not just a specific density. Sorry if this is not making sense, I am reading the question as given